# Choose the lesser evil incorrect Printf() statements: Fewer parameters vs extra parameters

Tags: c, compiler-errors, printf, compiler-warnings

```
A. printf("Values: X=%s Y=%s\n", x,y,z);
B. printf("Values: x=%s, Y=%s\n", x);
```

Both of the above printf() statements are incorrect: one has extra parameters, other has fewer parameters. I would like to choose between the lesser evil with an explanation. Can a modern C compiler help catch such problems? If yes, how does printf() implementor need to assist the compiler?

Comment: Sounds like a homework problem.  What do you think, and why?  perhaps comments could be made on your choices.

Comment: Yes, a modern C compiler will help with missing or extra (and incorrect) arguments. Which is worse is a matter of opinion: neither is acceptable, so there can be no choice as to which you use.

Comment: Try reading [N1570](http://chimera.roma1.infn.it/SP/COMMON/iso-iec-9899-1990.pdf) 7.21.6.1 The fprintf function, paragraph 2. Invoking undefined behavior is evil.

Comment: _I would like to choose between the lesser evil with an explanation._ Slight hint: `printf` is a variadic function which only takes the next variadic argument when it finds a format specifier in the format string. The remaining arguments are ignored.

Comment: Passing too many arguments does not have undefined behavior. C 2018 7.21.6.1 2 says “If the format is exhausted while arguments remain, the excess arguments are evaluated (as always) but are otherwise ignored.”

Comment: @MikeCAT: Invoking undefined behavior is not evil. There is no prohibition against it, and it is intended that behavior that is “undefined” in the C standard will be used in language extensions. Calling a graphics routine has behavior that is undefined by the C standard. Calling any operating system routine has behavior that is undefined by the C standard. Linking to any other programming language has behavior that is undefined by the C standard. Using any of the GCC built-ins, expression-statements, or other extensions has behavior that is undefined by the C standard.

Comment: @EricPostpischil it is legal, but either there is a format specifier missing, or there is uncertainty about which argument is unnecessary (apart from their naming). Voting to reopen. My reason to close was "opinion based".

Comment: @MikeCAT: These things are all necessary for practical use of C. C was not intended to be a walled garden like Java that tries to have the same behavior on all different implementations. It was intended to provide a core language that could be ported to different implementations, providing a base that programmers could use to program while still using extensions and particular features in those different implementations. Using behavior that is “undefined” in the C standard is a natural part of the language.

Answer (score 2):

> Both of the above printf() statements are incorrect: one has extra parameters, other has fewer parameters.

The first one is not incorrect according to the C standard. The rules for function calls in general, in C 2018 6.5.2.2, do not make it an error to pass unused arguments for a `...` in the function prototype. For `printf` specifically, C 2018 7.21.6.1 2 (about `fprintf`, which the specification for `printf` refers to) says extra arguments are harmless:

> … If the format is exhausted while arguments remain, the excess arguments are evaluated (as always) but are otherwise ignored…

Certainly if a programmer writes `printf("Values:  X=%s. Y=%s.\n", x, y, z);`, they might have made a mistake, and a compiler would be reasonable in pointing out this possibility. However, consider code such as:

```
printf(ComputedFormat, x, y, z);
```

Here it is reasonable that we wish to print different numbers of values in different circumstances, and the `ComputedFormat` reflects this. It would be tedious to write code for each case and dispatch to them with a `switch` statement. It is simpler to write one call and let the computed format determine how many values are printed. So it is not always an error to have more arguments than the conversion specifications use.

> I would like to choose between the lesser evil with an explanation.

The behavior of the latter code is not defined by the C standard. C 2018 7.21.6.1 2 also says:

> … If there are insufficient arguments for the format, the behavior is undefined…

Thus, no behavior may be relied on from the latter code, unless there is some guarantee from the C implementation.

> Can a modern C compiler help catch such problems?

Good modern C compilers have information about the specification of `printf` and, when the format argument is a string literal, they compare the number and types of the arguments to the conversion specifications in the string.

> If yes, how does printf() implementor need to assist the compiler?

The implementor of `printf` does not need to do anything except conform to the specification of `printf` in the C standard. The aid described above is performed by the C compiler with reference to the C standard; it does not rely on features of the particular `printf` implementation.

In some platforms, information about the number of arguments passed is provided to the called routine. In such platforms, a `printf` implementor could check whether too few arguments are provided and signal an error in some method.

Answer (score 0):

Eric Postpischil has already made a great answer that uses the most reliable source (the C standard), but I just want to post my own answer about *why* `printf` may behave as it does in both cases.

`printf` is a variadic function which can take a variable number of arguments. The way it knows how many you have passed is solely through the format string; every time it finds a format specifier, it takes the next argument out of the list (and assumes its type from which specifier has been used). Nothing would really happen to any extra arguments because since there is no specifier for them, the function will not even try to take them and they will not be printed. So you may be warned about the extra arguments by the compiler, but the behavior in the first example *is* well-defined.

The second, on the other hand, is definitely undefined behavior. Since there are not enough arguments to match the number of format specifiers in the string, eventually when it finds the second `%s`, it will try to take the next variadic argument, but the issue is that you haven't passed any. When this happens for me, it prints some garbage value in place of the format specifier that doesn't look too nice. Anything could happen in undefined behavior though. In this case, the function seems to try to take the next variadic argument from a CPU register / the stack (memory) and fetches some garbage value that happened to be there (though again, anything could happen with undefined behavior).

So in short:

```
printf("%s\n", "Hello", "World");
         |     |        ^^^^^^^ Ignored
         -------
```

and

```
printf("%s\n");   ?
         |        |
         ----------
```